# Adding business days to SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've look almost everywhere to find this.
I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `job_sheet`
LEFT JOIN deliveries ON job_sheet.job_id=deliveries.jID
WHERE job_sheet.completion=".ORDER_COMPLETE."
AND deliveries.ship_date>job_sheet.delivery_date
```

Which basically tells me which completed jobs were shipped past their `delivery_date` (DUE DATE).
However, the true delivery date is in reality 7 *business* days (holidays don't matter. basically just skipping the weekend) ahead than what's in the database.

What I need to be able to do is add 7 days to this section: `deliveries.ship_date>job_sheet.delivery_date + 7 business days`

My first thought was to use DATEADD() function, however It's rare that I use it and it's quite confusing on how to implement it in this situation.

The date is stored as: YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: How is your date stored in your database?

Comment: The date is stored as: YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: The database has no way of knowing what business days are.  Do you have a calendar table?  Do you have a list of holidays?

Comment: So it is stored in a VARCHAR column?  Or a DATE column?  BINARY?  TEXT?  The third position of a comma delimited VARBINARY column?

Comment: @bobwienholt It's stored in a DATE column

Comment: @GordonLinoff well it's not really an issue with the holidays. Basically just exclude weekends, regardless of any holiday. If the customer ordered something that's due on a holiday date, and the item was shipped after that day, then it's late.

Comment: if you only skip weekends and ignore holidays and all, then can't you just add `9` instead of `7`?

Comment: @dualed, 9 only works if initial date is mon, tue, wed.  11 days if initial date is a thu or fri.  a CASE statement should work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, adding 7 days to a date was easy enough with the help I got here. Since I specifically needed to add 7 business days to a certain date, I had to use some PHP along with the rest of my script. I used a custom DateHelper class to do the job.

```
class DateHelper {

    var $holidays = array("2010-07-04", "2010-09-06", "2010-09-23", "2010-10-11", "2010-11-01", "2010-11-11",  "2010-11-25", "2010-12-25");
    const oneday = 86400; 
    const weekend = 172800; 

    function addBusinessDays($start_date, $business_days)
    {

        if (date('N', $start_date) == 6)
        { // If start date is on Saturday
            $new_start_date = $start_date + self::weekend;
        } 
        elseif (date('N', $start_date) == 7)
        { // If start date is on Sunday
            $new_start_date = $start_date + self::oneday;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $new_start_date = $start_date;
        }

        $due_date = $new_start_date + $business_days * self::oneday;
        $due_date += floor($business_days / 5) * self::weekend;

        if (($business_days % 5) + date('N', $new_start_date) >= 6)
        {
            $due_date += self::weekend; // Add 2 days to compensate for the weekend
        }

        foreach($this->holidays as $holiday)
        {
            $time_stamp = strtotime($holiday);

            // If the holiday falls between the start date and end date
            // and is on a weekday
            // Or if $new_start_date is on a holiday
            if (($start_date <= $time_stamp && $time_stamp <= $due_date && date("N", $time_stamp) < 6) || date("Y-m-d", $new_start_date) == $holiday)
            {
                $due_date += self::oneday;
                if (date('N', $due_date) >= 6)
                {
                    // If due date on Saturday or Sunday
                    $due_date += self::weekend;
                }
            }
        }

        return $due_date;
    }
}
```

I combined this class to this:

```
//jobs that were shipped past their due date
public function totalShippedLate($offset = 7)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT deliveries.ship_date, job_sheet.delivery_date, deliveries.qty_shipped FROM `job_sheet` LEFT JOIN deliveries ON job_sheet.job_id=deliveries.jID WHERE job_sheet.completion=".jobInfo::ORDER_COMPLETE."") or die(mysql_error());
    $x = 0; // number of items shipped
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $date = new DateHelper();
        $offset_date = date("Y-m-d", $date->addBusinessDays(strtotime($data['delivery_date']), $offset));
        if($data['ship_date']>$offset_date)
        {
            $x += $data['qty_shipped']; 
        }
    }
    return $x;  
}
```

This will return the number of items that were shipped past their due date with a customizable offset

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `job_sheet`
   LEFT JOIN deliveries ON job_sheet.job_id=deliveries.jID
   WHERE job_sheet.completion=".ORDER_COMPLETE."
   AND  deliveries.ship_date> DATE_ADD(`job_deliveries.ship_date` , INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

[REFRENCE OF ADD_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: hope is this what you need .

Comment: This works just fine, although as I meantion to @saji89, it still shows the delivery_date being the same as it was before without the addition. Should it show the addition or does the SQL statement still do it's jobs regardless of what it shows?

Comment: the sql will do its job to add 7days , it will be `deliveries.ship_date>job_sheet.delivery_date + 7 business days`

Comment: Great, that's what I thought. I tried  to add 0 days (original state) and the rows were different than the + 7. I guess it's how it's interpreted. But does this consider the exclusion of weekends?

Thanks!!

Comment: it will add days without exclusion of the weekend . this it must be other work to do . this it add 7 days succeful

Comment: if you want to exceed the weekend and dont account saturday and sunday just add 9 instead of 7 . consider to accept the answer if it helped you my answer

Answer (score 1):

This should work, though I haven't tested it, as I don;t have an installed mysql instance to check:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `job_sheet`
LEFT JOIN deliveries ON job_sheet.job_id=deliveries.jID
WHERE job_sheet.completion=".ORDER_COMPLETE."
AND deliveries.ship_date>DATE_ADD(job_sheet.delivery_date,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: Well this works, meaning there are no errors, however, when I try it out, the job_sheet.delivery_date column still shows the same delvery date without the addition of 7 days. (im using MySQL workbench as a tester). Is it normal?

Comment: @Dimitri "the job_sheet.delivery_date column"?  Where is that specified?  The only column suggested by your example SELECT statement is the COUNT, which prevents listing each delivery individually.